# Programming the Feather 328p/ ATMega 328p

Tags: atmega328p, adafruit

I have an [Adafruit Feather 328P](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-328p-atmega328-atmega328p/arduino-ide-setup), which claims to be 'Arduino Compatible'. I believe I have set up my Arduino IDE correctly (according to the Adafruit link), but whenever I try to upload to the board I get the following:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_initialize(): failed
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

Problem uploading to board.  See https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/sections/360003198300 for suggestions.
```

The link provided does not seem to cover this exact error.

I have tried using several cables and multiple computers but still the same result. I am also running the ide as sudo as I simply got a 'permission denied' before. Any ideas?

This is a brand new board and fresh install of IDE. I have not connected anything to the board. When powered, the board simply sits blinking three times every couple seconds.

Attempting on Ubuntu Linux 20.04, but the same errors were seen on a mac computer.

Update: according to a comment on [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xadH_21vlIw), I was able to get it to connect and program by spamming the reset button a little during the connection process. Any ideas here?

Comment: You say you think you have set up the IDE correctly, but we don't know how you have set it up and is it correct. Would you add more information about it into your question.

Comment: I would have added a screenshot, but apparently in Gnome you can't do so when a menu is open (where the ide shows its board settings). But it is setup according to the Adafruit guide

Comment: OK, so it appears you are using Linux or some other unix system like BSDs. You might want to add that into your question so people don't suggest Windows solutions and you have to say they don't apply.

Comment: @Snappawapa to get a screenshot in ubuntu with a menu open, use 'scrot -d delay' which waits delay seconds before grabbing the screen, gives you time to get the menu open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I was able to get it to connect and program by spamming the reset button a little during the connection process. Any ideas here?**

As I expect you know (but a few readers might not) A typical bootloader program, pre-installed on most Arduino boards and compatibles, runs after a controller reset event and spends a while looking for serial activity before giving up and transferring control to any previously downloaded "sketch".

Your description suggests that there is some break in the process by which the Arduino IDE signals a reset that is communicated through USB to the USB-to-serial IC on the board (CP2104) and thence to the reset pin on the ATmega328.

In the past there has been some confusion over which serial control signals (e.g. DTR or RTS) should be used to signal a reset but I am pretty sure current versions of the IDE assert both.

The [feather schematic](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/50503) shows it used DTR rather than any other signal to effect a reset.

So that suggests maybe one of

- Your IDE is really really old.
- Your Unix/Linux configuration is blocking the relevant (virtual) serial signal line. (some `stty -cdtrdsr` weirdness?)
- The Unix/Linux driver for the Feather's CP2104 is blocking this signal (maybe you should replace the driver?)
- Your Feather's CP2104 isn't providing this signal due to some defect or a broken pin or broken track. Maybe some partial short is holding the line high more strongly than the CP2104 can pull down, but insufficiently to defeat the reset switch.
- something else?

While clicking the IDE's "Upload" button, it might be interesting to monitor the CP2104's DTR pin with, for example, a logic probe of some sort.